# Extract BearerToken from LinqToTwitter IAuthorizer

Tags: twitter, linq-to-twitter

Hopefully a simple answer to what I think is a simple question.

Is it possible to Extract the BearerToken from the IAuthorizer once I am authenticated?  After using LinqToTwitter to authorize, I want to make my own API calls and I need the BearerToken to do so.

Thank you for your time in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about `ApplicationOnlyAuthorizer`. The demos assign to `IAuthorizer`, so you need to convert to `ApplicationOnlyAuthorizer` to expose the `BearerToken`, like this:

```
        await auth.AuthorizeAsync();
        string bearerToken = (auth as ApplicationOnlyAuthorizer).BearerToken;
```

Comment: That's the one!  Thank you Joe!